# Efficiently calculate averages of keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
    'TICKET_URL/3250': {'cycle_time': 0, 'lead_time': 2496441},
    'TICKET_URL/3323': {'cycle_time': 346087, 'lead_time': 508469},
    'TICKET_URL/3328': {'cycle_time': 249802, 'lead_time': 521211},
    'TICKET_URL/3352': {'cycle_time': 504791, 'lead_time': 504791},
    'TICKET_URL/3364': {'cycle_time': 21293, 'lead_time': 21293},
    'TICKET_URL/3367': {'cycle_time': 102558, 'lead_time': 189389},
    'TICKET_URL/3375': {'cycle_time': 98735,  'lead_time': 98766}
}
```

How can I efficiently calculate the average `cycle_time` and `lead_time` (independently). Right now I'm iterating over the dictionary twice - once for `cycle_time` and once for `lead_time`. Can I do this in a single pass?

Currently:

```
average_cycle = (
    sum([story["cycle_time"] for story in stories.values()]) / len(stories)
)
```

Comment: Loop over `stories.values()`... extract the cycle_time and lead_time on each iteration, getting their sum, then divide by the length of stories?

Comment: Doing it in a single pass doesn't really make an improvement.

Comment: Note, in my time writing Python, I've come to accept that two passes over a container like this are *rarely* an issue. And if you have readable code that does it in two passes, just learn to enjoy it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind pandas,

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data.values()).mean().to_dict()
```

will produce:

```
{'cycle_time': 189038.0, 'lead_time': 620051.4285714285}
```

As a bonus, it will also handle missing values nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```py
count = len(stories.values())
cycle_total = 0
lead_total = 0
for story in stories.values():
    cycle_total += story.get("cycle_time", 0)
    lead_total += story.get("lead_time", 0)

cycle_avg = cycle_total / count
lead_avg = lead_total / count
```

Comment: `count = len(stories.values())` can just be `count = len(stories)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the issue with your current implementation. I would suggest adding a `avg()` function to maybe enhance readability:

```
def avg(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x) 
avg_cycle = avg([story['cycle_time'] for story in stories.values()])
avg_lead_time = avg([story['lead_time'] for story in stories.values])
```

Comment: this does two passes.